# Get all members that do not match between 2 lists

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am using vb.net :(

I have 2 list collections and i want to return a 3rd collection where the members i 1 collection do not exist in another.

So, for example I have this basic Class Object

```
Class Person
    Public Property FirstName As String
End Class
```

I now create 2 lists:

```
Dim l1 As List(Of Person) = New List(Of Person)()
Dim l2 As List(Of Person) = New List(Of Person)()

Dim p1 As Person = New Person()
p1.FirstName = "andy"
l1.Add(p1)

Dim p2 As Person = New Person()
p2.FirstName = "john"
l1.Add(p2)

Dim p3 As Person = New Person()
p3.FirstName = "david"
l2.Add(p3)

Dim p4 As Person = New Person()
p4.FirstName = "john"
l2.Add(p4)
```

want i want is to get a new list with these entries:

```
andy
david
```

I have this so far:

```
Dim newList = From c1 In l1, c2In l2
               Where c2.FirstName <> c1.FirstName
               Select c1.FirstName
```

which gives me:

```
andy
andy
john
```

I admit my linq is great....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way is using `All` extension method:

```
Dim newList = From c1 In l1
              Where l2.All(Function(c2) c2.FirstName <> c1.FirstName)
              Select c1.FirstName
```

Another solution could be using `Except` extension method:

```
Dim newList=l1.Select(Function(c1) c1.FirstName).Except(l2.Select(Function(c2) c2.FirstName));
```

### Update:

I noticed now that you want the exclusive element from both list. You can concat both list of names and apply later a `GroupBy` to get only the names that appear one time:

```
Dim newList=l1.Select(Function(c1) c1.FirstName).Concat(l2.Select(Function(c2) c2.FirstName))
           .GroupBy(Function(c) c)
           .Where(Function(g) g.Count()=1)
           .Select(Function(g) g.Key);
```

Comment: lol, sorry, I don't know why I thought it was an intersection but it is an except ;)

Comment: @octavioccl +1 from me

Comment: I have tried both examples but they both only give me 1  name which is 'andy' and no 'david' :(

Comment: Oh now was that I noticed that david is in l2, let me update my answer

Comment: @AndrewSimpson I have updated my solution, I'm sure it must exist a better solution but that was that came to my mind for now. If I find something better I'll let you know

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Dim List1 = l1.Select(Function(e1) e1.FirstName).Except(l2.Select(Function(e2) e2.FirstName)).ToList

    Dim List2 = l2.Select(Function(e2) e2.FirstName).Except(l1.Select(Function(e2) e2.FirstName)).AsEnumerable
```

'merge

```
    For Each item As String In List2
        If Not List1.Contains(item) Then
            List1.Add(item)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Hi @dejan87, notice both list are `Person` type, you need to define a custom `IEqualityComparer`, check this link  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2. Comment about that and you have my vote ;)